# How to exclude a directory in covxml or bullshtml?

Tags: code-coverage

I can do these steps to get coverage information in covsrc

`covselect -f test.cov -d`

`covselect -f test.cov -a dir_i_want/`

`covsrc -f test.cov`

But when I use covxml or bullshtml, the settings i did above don't work.

So, how to exclude a directory or only include directories I want?

Answer (score 0):

What I found worked for me was to use a import/export file.

```
covselect --file file.cov --import <importfile>
```

"folder" seem to need to end with a forward slash or they are ignored

```
exclude folder path/to/dir/
include source path/to/src.cpp
exclude function path/to/src.cpp:name::space::class::function(param& p)
```